# Spring-yarn cross-platform FsShell problems

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hadoop-yarn

I'm working from the Spring YARN [example](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-yarn-basic) hosted at GitHub.  I have the basic project shell working; that is, the submission from a **Windows** client to a remote Hadoop **Linux** cluster works and the YARN container code is executed.  In my container, I'm doing a simple test of `FsShell` as suggested in the example.

```
@Autowired
private Configuration configuration;

@OnContainerStart
public void containerStart() throws IOException {
  try (FsShell shell = new FsShell(configuration)) {
    for (FileStatus s : shell.ls(false, "/")) {
      log.info(s);
    }
  }
}
```

When the container code executes, I am getting the following error:

```
Application application_1427147939282_0014 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1427147939282_0014_000002 exited with exitCode: 1 due to: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1427147939282_0014_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Exception message: /bin/bash: line 0: fg: no job control
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: /bin/bash: line 0: fg: no job control
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:702)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:197)
```

I understand that this is a well-known failure mode when submitting jobs from Windows clients to Linux and that it is related to passing the environment from Windows.  This is hinted at in the YARN [container environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/yarn.html#yarn:containerenvironment) documentation:

> Be carefull if passing environment variables between different systems. For example if running a client on Windows and passing variables to Application Master running on Linux, execution wrapper in Yarn may silently fail.

In the Spring [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.2.0.M1/reference/html/springandhadoop-yarn.html#using-the-spring-for-apache-yarn-javaconfig) for configuring YARN with annotation-based configuration, it indicates how the configuration for YARN may be set using annotations.  I have added the classes as indicated (see below) but as far as I can tell, the configuration is not being used.  I have tried a few experiments that would throw an exception and I never see any change.  I've included this code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableYarn(enable = Enable.CONTAINER)
public class ContainerConfiguration extends SpringYarnConfigurerAdapter {

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public void configure(YarnEnvironmentConfigurer environment) throws Exception {
    super.configure(environment);
    environment.includeLocalSystemEnv(false);
  }
}
```

I'm new to Spring-Boot and the annotation-based configuration style.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  Thanks!